# Show that $E[\mu_i^2|X_i]=\sigma^2$ and $Var(\mu_i|X_i)=\sigma^2$

Tags: regression, self-study, variance, linear-model, expected-value

I'm a little stuck on this review problem so help would be greatly appreciated!

Q: We have the regression model $Y_i=\beta_0+\beta_1X_i+\mu_i$ and we assume that the expected errors are $0$. We also know that the asymptotic variance of $\hat{\beta_1}$ is:
$$\frac{Var(\mu_i(X_i-E(X_i))}{Var(X_i)}$$

EDITED:
Now I have to Show that IF $E[\mu_i^2|X_i]=\sigma^2$ THEN $Var(\mu_i|X_i)=\sigma^2$.

My thoughts: What does knowing the asymptotic variance have to do with anything in this problem? Can I simply solve the following equation?

$$Var(\mu_i^2|X_i)=E[\mu_i^2|X_i] - E([\mu_i|X_i])^2$$

But how?

Step by step help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the definition of $\sigma^2$?

Comment: $\sigma^2$ is the variance, I'm not sure what you mean. Apologies, I added the homework tag although this is not homework.

Comment: You haven't supplied enough information to answer this question. You are asking us to *show* that $\sigma^2$ is a particular variance. But how is $\sigma^2$ defined in the first place?

Comment: My apologies as I think I made a small typo. The question should be: IF $E[\mu_{i^2}|X_i]=\sigma^2$ THEN SHOW that $Var(\mu_i|X_i)=\sigma^2$.

Comment: I worry about using $\mu$ for the *error term* ... such a choice is likely to mislead novice (or even merely unwary) readers.

Comment: Can you edit your title and question body to reflect your changed question?

Comment: "we assume that the expected errors are 0" - is this in conditional expectations? can you write it as an equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you talking about residuals or disturbances in the regression. You state that

$Var(μ_i|X_i)=E[μ^2_i|X_i]−E([μ_i|X_i])^2$

and that the  that the expected errors are 0 (i.e. $E([μ_i|X_i]=0$. Then your result follows immediately

Comment: This is a good answer (+1) but essentially does someone's homework. It goes some way beyond the "hints and guidance" called for in the `self-study` [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for routine bookwork problems. I think it would have been better (at least initially) to replace your text following the first equation with something like "can you say anything about the term involving the expected error $E([\mu_i|X_i])$?"

Comment: So my original variance equation is correct? I was in doubt as to whether it is correct or not!

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the wiki on self-study. The variance term should refer to $var(\mu_i)$ and not $var(\mu_i^2)$.